# Apache container with Server-Status

Tags: httpd, docker

Have someone here setup successfully apache with server status inside of a container to allow access from the host? I have already tried with --add-host param at docker to then allow that host at the config file but I still get the Forbidden Error Message

The httpd config file for server status is set as:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from mainserver
</Location>
```

I'm creating the docker container with this command:
`docker run -e 80:80 httpdimage /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND`

From the host, then I'm doing the test with this curl command:
`curl http://localhost/server-status`

And I get then the error message:

> ## Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /server-status
>   on this server.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be going on here.

First, from the perspective of your container, your host has the address of your `docker0` bridge; this is the default route inside your container, so you can get it like this:

```
host_address=$(ip route | awk '$1 == "default" {print $3}')
```

You can have an `ENTRYPOINT` script or something substitute this into your Apache configuration when you start the container, giving you something like:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 172.47.42.1
</Location>
```

If you are running Apache 2.4, this won't work.  In Apache 2.4, the `Allow` and `Deny` directives have been replaced with a newer syntax, so you actually need:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Require ip 172.17.42.1
</Location>
```

This is what finally worked on my system.